How to stop the listener in SoapUI after running a test case with a test step that is a mock?
I am running the test case AT_retry, which has a mock as a test step called at (executed after the step indicated in the Start Step). The mock at correctly captures the request.
Then I run another test case AT_positive, which also has the mock at. This one, however, does not capture the request because SoapUI does not stop listening on the mock at that was started in the first test case, even though the test case AT_retry has already completed.
How can I force SoapUI to stop listening after the test case ends? Currently, the only solution is to restart SoapUI.

I tried:
def mockServiceName = "at"
def mockService = testRunner.testCase.getProject().getMockServiceByName(mockServiceName)

if (mockService) {
    if (mockService.isRunning()) {
        mockService.stop()
    } else {
        log.info("Mock service was not run.")
    }
} else {
    log.error("Not found: ${mockServiceName}.")
}


...and many similar options.
